# antlr4 grammar for interpreter - defining entry point in input file

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to get my head around how to cause antlr4 to execute at a given point in an input file and not at the top. I've taken advice from SO users and started a solution using Antlr4 Visitors.

My input file declares 'BASIC' like subroutines and has a Main at the bottom. An example input file:

```
   #Program hello;

   Sub mysub1()
      print "please dont call me but I know you will";
   End Sub

   Sub mysub2()
     #code
   End Sub

   Main() #execute code from here
     call mysub2;
   EndMain
```

Unsurprisingly its executing any code in the Sub's because it doesn't know any different than to start at the top.

My grammar file includes

```
    prog
 :  stat* 'Main' stat* 'EndMain' EOF
 ;

stat
 : call_sub 
 | assignment
 | if_stat
 | while_stat 
     ...
```

So the first stat* get executed - and that's my point, how do I get the execution to start at Main. e.g. How do I discover/source the 'Main' token/rule then start visiting there, rather than the top of the file/tree?

Many thanks in advance.

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to declare a boolean maindone=false in the extended BaseVisitor class, then in my

```
public Value visitBeginSublabel(@NotNull t5Parser.BeginSublabelContext ctx) { 
    if (maindone == false){
        subs.put(ctx.ID().toString(),ctx); // stash the function/sub name to HashMap
        //main not done. skipping activity
        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

and when visiting visitMain

```
@Override public Value visitMain(@NotNull t5Parser.MainContext ctx) { 
    maindone=true;
    ...
```

This seems to have done the trick. I also tidied up the grammar so only variables could be declared at global level and some other necessary items.

I'm not saying this is the perfect way to do this exercise but certainly it has worked. I declared also

```
public Map< String,t5Parser.BeginactivitylabelContext>subs = new HashMap<String,t5Parser.BeginactivitylabelContext>();
```

Because I wanted a quick lookup of subroutine names when I called them from another function, so in my visitCall function

```
  public Value visitCall(@NotNull t5Parser.CallContext ctx) { 
            this.visit(subs.get(ctx.ID().toString()));
         ...
```

Where my source file has a

```
Main
   call myfunction()
EndMain
```

Only been doing this stuff a week so looking for advice and better answers.